# How to disable Jetpack modules such as Stats?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, statistics

I want to disable some of the Jetpack modules such as Stats in order to check if they make the web site slower or not. But I couldn't see an option to disable modules one by one.

Of course, one can disable the Jetpack plugin as a whole. Is there a way to disable Stats module only?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press the `"Learn More"` button for each Jetpack Module, you will get a `"Deactivate"` button showing up to the right.

[image: Disabling the WP Stats Module]

There is also a fork call Jetpack Lite

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack-lite/

> A NOT official "lite" fork of Jetpack plugin containing only Stats and
>   WP.me Shortlinks modules. All other modules removed (files and code).

Comment: This answer is totally correct. I also wanted to include this link to the official Jetpack support page, which covers this question and others: http://jetpack.me/support/#turn-off-jetpack-modules

p.s. Jetpack, hiding the deactivate button behind a Learn More button is a horrible dark pattern and you should feel bad.

Answer (score 3):

The process to deactivate a module on Jetpack has changed.

Instructions are here: **[Control Jetpack’s Modules on One Page](https://jetpack.com/support/control-jetpacks-modules-on-one-page/)**

Basically, you need to go to `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules` and there you can find a `Deactivate` button for every module.

Answer (score 2):

Functions to disable and remove from the settings page individual jetpack modules.

```
function jherve_kill_monitor ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['monitor'] );
    return $modules;
}   
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jherve_kill_monitor' );

function jherve_kill_sso ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['sso'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jherve_kill_sso' );

function jeherve_kill_notes ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['notes'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_notes' );

function jeherve_kill_comments ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['comments'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_comments' );

function jeherve_kill_carousel ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['carousel'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_carousel' );

function jeherve_kill_likes ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['likes'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_likes' );

function jeherve_kill_post_by_email ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['post-by-email'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_post_by_email' );

function jeherve_kill_omnisearch ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['omnisearch'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_omnisearch' );

function jeherve_kill_gravatar_hovercards ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['gravatar-hovercards'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_gravatar_hovercards' );

function jeherve_kill_contact_form ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['contact-form'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_contact_form' );

function jeherve_kill_widget_visibility ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['widget-visibility'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_widget_visibility' );

function jeherve_kill_photon ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['photon'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_photon' );

function jeherve_kill_videopress ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['videopress'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_videopress' );

function jeherve_kill_latex ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['latex'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_latex' );

function jeherve_kill_enhanced_distribution ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['enhanced-distribution'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_enhanced_distribution' );

function jeherve_kill_infinite_scroll ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['infinite-scroll'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_infinite_scroll' );

function jeherve_kill_subscriptions ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['subscriptions'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_subscriptions' );

function jeherve_kill_tiled_gallery ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['tiled-gallery'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_tiled_gallery' );

function jeherve_kill_vaultpress ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['vaultpress'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_vaultpress' );

function jeherve_kill_mobile_push ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['mobile-push'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_mobile_push');

function jeherve_kill_stats ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['stats'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_stats' );

function jeherve_kill_sharedaddy ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['sharedaddy'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_sharedaddy' );

function jeherve_kill_after_the_deadline ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['after-the-deadline'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_after_the_deadline' );

function jeherve_kill_publicize ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['publicize'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_publicize' );

function jeherve_kill_gplus_authorship ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['gplus-authorship'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_gplus_authorship' );

function jeherve_kill_shortcodes ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['shortcodes'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_shortcodes' );

function jeherve_kill_minileven ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['minileven'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_minileven' );

function jeherve_kill_custom_css ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['custom-css'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_custom_css' );

function jeherve_kill_widgets ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['widgets'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_widgets' );

function jeherve_kill_wpcc ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['wpcc'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_wpcc' );

function jeherve_kill_json_api ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['json-api'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_json_api' );

function jeherve_kill_shortlinks ( $modules ) {
    unset( $modules['shortlinks'] );
    return $modules;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_get_available_modules', 'jeherve_kill_shortlinks' );
```

Comment: Why? Only 1 function is necessary.

Comment: Because it's nice to pick and choose what you want. Also having only 5 or six items on my jetpack menu at all is a small convenience

Comment: You can pick an choose by commenting or uncommenting too but I understand what you meant now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to disable each module without any codes.

GO to Jetpack dashboard and scroll to the bottom. Find "Modules" tab on the footer and click it.

Inside that you can find all the modules and you can activate/deactivate each module as you wish. That is how I deactivated WP Stats module without any code.